# RadGrid how to disable Row Click in some Cells? asp.net

Tags: telerik, click, row, cell, radgrid

This question might be a bit specific since it invovles a specific type of grid called RadGrid from Telerik.

I have a RadGrid with 5 columns with the EnablePostBackOnRowClick set to true, but I only want the RowClick event to be executed on 3 grid cells, I don't want this event to be executed on the fisrt and last cell (column), is there anyway to disable the RowClick event from being triggered when you click on these particular cells? Is there a way to limit the RowClick event  to just the 3 cells/columns in the middle?

Comment: Submit this question in a support ticket to telerik.  They'll respond to you within 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Telerik demo:  [Grid Cell Selection](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/cellselection/defaultcs.aspx)

If you specify an `OnCellSelected` client method, you could check which column the cell belongs to, then send an AJAX request back to the server (if if it's one of your 3 columns) and put your remaining logic in the server-side AJAX request handler method. I'm not sure if the server-side `ItemCommand` method can detect which cell you clicked on, but try that first, and if it doesn't work then the AJAX route would suffice. Also, you need at least the 2012 build of RadControls.

This is the markup for setting the appropriate settings:

```
<ClientSettings>
    <ClientEvents OnCellSelected="cellSelected"></ClientEvents>
    <Selecting CellSelectionMode="SingleColumn"></Selecting>
</ClientSettings>
```